# How to get rid of extra fullstops(.) from a string or cleaning data before processing?

Tags: python, regex

**Example:**

```
string_1 = 'Hello,How are you...?'
string_2 = 'I am having problem....using this device..'
```

I want to remove the extra `'.'`. I want something to work like `find&replace`. I thought of including RegEx for this but not good at it.

I tried the below approach:

```
import re     
v = re.sub('.', '.', string_1)
```

But this not give me what I desire. How to manipulate the first `'.'` in `re.sub()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `+` in regex and negate `.` since it matches all in regex

**Code:**

```
re.sub("\.+", ".", string_2)
```

**Output:**

```
'I am having problem.using this device.'
```

Comment: So if in any case I am cleaning my strings I can pass like `"\.!?+"` for removing the repeating characters?

Comment: @KevinGuan I used this `string_1 = 'Hello,,,??How are you...????'` `v = re.sub('([\.\!\?])+', r'\1',string_1)` output - > Hello,,,?How are you? I didn't get any fullstops in it

Comment: @NikhilParmar you have to change your regex see this `re.sub(r'([.?!])\1+', r'\1','I am having problem.!!!..???..using this device..' )
`

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
v = re.sub('\.+', '.', string_1)
```

You have to escape the `'.'` because otherwise it matches any character at all. The `\.+` therefore matches at least one `'.'` character. `string_2` becomes

```
'I am having problem.using this device.'
```

and `string_1` becomes:

```
'Hello,How are you.?'
```

So you may want some spaces in there too.